# How to covert string of phone number to int or float without .0 at the end?

Tags: php, laravel

Value from database is 63906xxxxxxx which is a phone number.Now, how to pull this number exactly 12 digit since i have a 32 bit version of PhP.

Here is my code for getting as string:
$contactNum = $ngo_cotactNo;

```
        $numeric_indexed_array = array_values($contactNum);
        $n = $numeric_indexed_array[0];
```

dd($n);
output:"639063449729"

Here is my code for getting as string converted to int:
$contactNum = $ngo_cotactNo;

```
        $numeric_indexed_array = array_values($contactNum);
        $n = $numeric_indexed_array[0];
        $number = (int) $n;
        dd($number);
```

output : 2147483647
string to float
output : 639063449729.0

What i want is the whole number 639063449729  so that i can use it for passing to the API for my sms messaging.I've been working on this since yesterday but no luck.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it from a string to an Int or a float? probably best to keep it as a a string.

Comment: it should stay as a string

Comment: See the discussion here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124546/datatype-for-phone-number-varchar-int-or-bigint - there may be reasons why it makes sense for phone numbers to be stored as a data type other than string

Comment: @AndrewL - The reason is this number should be pass as valid phone number not as string parameter since it is use for sending message to this particular number.

Comment: @nogad - I am using  chikka api for messaging and my only problem is the right convertion of string to number  for php/laravel.I've search everywhere yet still no luck for it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert phone numbers into integers or floats. In a 32 bit environment positive integers going up to 2^31, which is a little bit more than 2 000 000 000. It is simply impossible to place a twelve digit number in 32 bits. Don't use floats neither. Floats having a limited precision, so your phone number might be rounded to the next representable number. Please leave them in a string.

Wikipedia says:

> In the international telephone network, the format of telephone
>   numbers is standardized by ITU-T recommendation E.164. This code
>   specifies that the entire number should be 15 digits or shorter, and
>   begin with a country prefix.

Comment: Problem solved:  I simply set the data type to BIGINT in my database.Thanks to your answers. I've learned something out of it.